# Запоминается нажатие кнопки. Isset возвращает 1

Tags: php

Добрый вечер. Заранее извиняюсь за плохо отформатированный код - не получилось.
Проблема: запоминается функция isset после того, как нажал на кнопку. То есть фактически состояние кнопки - нажата, хотя я её нажал только 1 раз. Соответсвенно ветка, приведённая ниже, выполняется всегда. Удаётся сбросить эффект вводом функции unset. Объясните ошибку. Использую денвер

```
<input name="add_class" type="submit" value="Добавить новое занятие" class="button_left">
<?php
      //unset($_POST['add_class']);
      if (isset($_POST['add_class'])){
      $query = "INSERT INTO monday (time, class, instructor) values ('15-50','Ashtanga','Letosheva Ekaterina')";
      $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Ошибка при добавлении данных: ".mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду ситуацию, когда при перезагрузке страницы вновь посылаются данные?

Comment: Зачем сабмиту name? А isset($_POST['add_class']) даст true при любых состояниях, заполненных или незаполненных форм. Сформулируйте вопрос более точно, неясно что у вас неработает.

Comment: А как вы проверяете этот код без нажатия кнопки? Обновляете страницу и нажимаете "Да, отправить данные повторно"?

Comment: name нужен, потому что там несколько кнопок на форме, и нужно проверять каждую. Ну а как ещё идентифицировать кнопку? Сейчас получается, что после первого нажатия кнопки она "запоминается" и в дальнейшем код работает так, что как будто я её нажимаю каждый раз. А я просто перезагружаю страницу

Comment: """ А как вы проверяете этот код без нажатия кнопки? Обновляете страницу и нажимаете "Да, отправить данные повторно"? """ - да, именно так

Comment: сделайте redirect после успешного сабмита.

Comment: Непонятно, почему isset всегда 1, даже если пустой инпут. Название функции говорит же само за себя. Я хочу, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы не выполнялся код внутри if. Хотя бы понять, почему он всегда выполняется

Comment: потому что вы **пересылаете данные** вам и браузер об этом говорит, вы соглашаетесь, а потом удивляетесь.

Answer (score 1):

Прочтите что такое `isset` - а вот форма в этой ситуации всегда возвращает пустую строку, которая по `isset` всегда **true**. Проверяй через `!empty(...)`, или просто ***boolean***